# C++ strange behaviour with function call by value

Tags: c++, gsl

I have an object which is a class interface to the matrix struct found in the GNU Scientific Library

```
typedef double real_t;
typedef unsigned short index_t;
class matrix
{
        gsl_matrix* m;
    public:
        matrix(index_t rows, index_t columns, real_t val);
}

matrix::matrix(index_t rows, index_t columns, real_t val)
{
    m=gsl_matrix_alloc(rows,columns);
    gsl_matrix_set_all(m, val);
    return;
}

index_t matrix::rows(void)
{
    return m->size1;
}

index_t matrix::columns(void)
{
    return m->size2;
}
```

the problem is that if I use a function taking the matrix object by value like this one:

```
void test_function(const matrix m){};
```

and use it in a program like this one

```
int main()
{
    matrix m(4,4,1);
    cout << m.rows() << '\t' << m.columns() << endl;
    test_function(m);
    cout << m.rows() << '\t' << m.columns() << endl;
}
```

I surprisingly obtain that the number of rows of the matrix object m is modified by the function `test_function` to garbage value, even if I put the keyword const before the argument and the call is made by value. 
But the strangest thing is that if I use a function that makes use of call by reference like this one:

```
void test_function(const matrix &m){};
```

nothing happens and everything seems to be all right.

As far as I know, call by value shouldn't be able to modify the argument of the function, 
especially if the function does nothing as in this case and especially if I explicitly use the keyword const before the argument name in the function prototype...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I also have defined the copy constructor for the matrix class as

```
matrix& matrix::operator= (const matrix& src)
{
    gsl_matrix_memcpy(m,src.m);
    return *this;
}
```

which does a complete copy (I guess) of the gsl_matrix struct

EDIT:

Ok, I think I've finally understood: the call by value function creates a shallow copy object that just contains the pointer to the real object, when test_function terminates all local variables are destroyed, so the destructor of the matrix class (which is defined but omitted here for the sake of brevity) is called, but in this way the object in the main (to which the local m points to) is destroyed together with the local variable.. Anyway I solved the problem defining a proper copy constructor that performs a complete (deep) copy of the object and then using call by reference which should be better for heavy computation. Thanks a lot to everybody for your help!

Comment: How is it that your `matrix` constructor has 3 parameters but you create `m` with 4?

Comment: passing argument by value calls the copy constructor, which can do anything.

Comment: to Alexey Frunze: you're right, that's 'cause in my real program there's also a constructor with 4 args that just init the matrix to random values between the last two arguments, now I changed it anyway

Comment: That's not a copy constructor you added - that's a non-canonical assignment operator (should be const matrix&).  The copy constructor would be matrix::matrix(const matrix& src) {}

Comment: @MadKeithV Thanks!! I did as you suggested and it works, but i don't understand why.. if I write in the copy constructor m=src.m; , it returns to the same behaviour as before, but I don't understand why, even if a pointer to the original object is actually passed to the function, the object in the main got changed since function test_function really does nothing..

Comment: I suspect that your "m" member actually contains a pointer to actual data inside it - it's the shallow copy of "m" in your matrix' default copy constructor that causes the problem.  The data behind "m" changes, and both copies of your matrix point to the same m data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an argument by value, compiler calls the one-argument copy constructor to create the value in the function. If you do not provide a copy constructor, compiler generates one for you.

In the example above, compiler generated copy constructor makes shallow copy of the inner matrix pointer. When the newly generated matrix in the function goes out of scope, the shallow copied pointer gets deleted also. My guess is this is the reason.

You could check this by providing a copy constructor which does not copy the gsl_matrix pointer.

Comment: I tried to change the copy constructor as you indicated, but nothing changed, anyway i do not understand how the original object in the main could be changed, since, even if the local pointer variable in the function get lost, the original pointer m.m should remain unchanged

Comment: as MadKeithV pointed out I was not using the standard copy constructor, now it works, but I still do not understand how could the original object be modified since the function test_function really does nothing, anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: @user2318607  The memory gets released when the temp pointer is deleted.  That memory is then reused by the program for something else.  Your original pointer is still pointing at this memory being used for something else so you see the changes.  Follow the rule of three http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29  Note some compilers write over deallocated memory in debug builds to make this type of bug easier to detect, so it often doesn't matter that you didn't do anything.

Answer (score 2):

because the default copy ctor just makes a shallow copy, that is, it just copies the value of pointer m, instead of allocate a new one.

Comment: thanks, because I didn't know that the copy ctor was called in function call by value, but actually in my code I have a copy constructor defined, which I omitted because I thought it was unimportant, now i edit